# Is it safe to apply voltage to buffer output?

Tags: buffer, hardware

I want to design a SDI-12 interface and I am using [this schematic](https://www.daycounter.com/Circuits/SDI-12/SDI-12-Interface.phtml) as a starting point. In receive mode, the 5V SDI-12 data signal will reach UART RX via the transistor Q1, but will also reach the output of the buffer U1 (I my case, it is a [74LV1T126GVH](https://ro.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/74LV1T126-1318689.pdf)).

So, is there a risk of damaging the buffer when applying the RX voltage on its output? If so, what solution is there to this problem?

[image]

Comment: Paste the schematic into your question but leave the link for reference.

Comment: @Andyaka I've included the schematic.

Comment: Have you read the buffer datasheet if it allows it or not?

Comment: Is the buffer active (OE low) usually ? Is it during this time that is your concern ? Have you added the 510R resistors yourself ? Is there a reason why you couldn't clamp the voltage to say < Vcc instead of the 7.5V ?

Comment: @Justme The datasheet does not specify anything about applying voltage to its output. It only refers to inputs.

Comment: @citizen Usually, OE will be low. Yes, this is the time that is my concern (when OE is low, then it is in reception mode). The resistors and other parts are recommended in the SDI-12 standard.

Comment: @CristianM The datasheet does mention it. But beware that Nexperia datasheet says VCC+0.5V max in high-Z and 4.6V when unpowered, and TI datasheet says 4.6V for both high-z and unpowered. But it's a three state buffer, if it can drive 5V onto a three state bus, it can be expected to allow 5V on output when some other 5V device is driving the bus.

Comment: How do you intend to power U1?

Comment: Table 9 : Limiting Values. VO : VCC + 0.5V. So yes there is a risk, or no it is not safe.

Comment: @Justme Ok. Thanks for clearing it out. I intend to power it at 5V, so it will not be a problem.

Comment: @BrianDrummond VCC will be 5V, so there is will be no problem as I understood.

Comment: @BruceAbbott At 5V.

Comment: If D1 provides input protection at 7.5V and VCC=5V then what justifies that there is no problem?

Comment: @BrianDrummond That schematic is a starting point. I will use a Zener diode with a lower Vz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer will not work. And the schematic violates some of SDI-12 tranceiver requirements, such as DC impedance to GND.

The buffer will also not tolerate 5V on output if it is unpowered (VCC=0), so it will load down the bus outside the allowed limits of SDI-12 specs.

It needs an inverting buffer like in the example schematics, unless the UART_TX polarity can be set in the MCU. Sometimes UART polarity can be set, but is it separate for TX and RX is another question. As it is now, UART_TX and UART_RX will have opposite polarity, as the FET inverts the data.

Otherwise the schematic is almost a copy of reference design from SDI-12 standard.

Comment: Yes, you are right and thanks for noticing these issues. This schematic is a starting point; the 200k resistor and 3.3nF capacitor to ground are missing and I will add them. The buffer will not be powered off, so there will not be any issues regarding the tolerance to 5V. I missed the fact that SDI-12 uses a negative logic; however, I can't use that buffer (SN74LVC1G240) because it does not accept 3.3V signals when powered at 5V. I will invert UART TX with the inverting buffer 74LV1T04. Now, the TX and RX polarity should be fine on both sides (MCU and SDI-12). Please tell if you agree.

Comment: I don't see the point of using two chips for this. If you go to chip manufacturer or distributor websites and do a parametric search for TTL compatible inverting three state buffers that work at 5V supply, I'm sure you find a suitable part. Maybe the MCU supports 5V levels so simply a pull-up to 5V is enough?

Comment: The host is a I2C-UART bridge (MAX14830) and does not support 5V levels. Basically I need a 3-state inverting buffer with non-inverted enable input (active high OE), because it is controlled by !UART_RTS (which is not under my manual control). I've search several chip manufacturers' websites, but did not find a chip that meets these requirements.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Tri-state buffers.

When one output or one input is not in use, it can be set as high impedance with the EN or -OE pins. And so the input or output is protected up to Vcc or even sometimes above that.